# How to show another MsgBox if credentials is correct in Login Form at VB.net?

Tags: sql, mysql, vb.net

I am trying to make a login form in vb.net and the credentials are saved from Myqsl database. However there is something wrong whenever I try to input code for MsgBox whether the credentials are correct or not.

When I use this code, even if the credentials I input is valid, the "Invalid Credentials" MsgBox shows instead of "Login Succesful" MsgBox

```
 Private Sub btLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btLogin.Click
        Opencon()
        Try
            cmd.Connection = dhel
            If cmd.CommandText = "Select * from credentials_tb where Username='" & tbUser.Text & "' and Password='" & tbPwd.Text & "'" Then
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Login Succesful.")
                dhel.Close()
                Me.Hide()
            Else
                MsgBox("Invalid Credentials.")
                dhel.Close()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

Then i I use this code the "Login Succesful" MsgBox appears when the credential I input is correct, but I also need one for when it is wrong. I searched already, I don't know if I searched enough, but I somehow can't find a way to fix it.

```
Private Sub btLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btLogin.Click
        Opencon()
        Try
            cmd.Connection = dhel
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from credentials_tb where Username='" & tbUser.Text & "' and Password='" & tbPwd.Text & "'"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Login Succesful.")
                dhel.Close()
                Me.Hide()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

Comment: Why are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute a query in the first place? I think you need to do a bit more reading on ADO.NET and what methods to call when. There's plenty of informatiuon around but here are some code examples of my own: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases

Comment: Then should I remove it? I just followed our instructors sample from the board.

Comment: I can't see what your instructor showed you so I can't say whether you followed the example properly or not. `ExecuteNonQuery` is for executing SQL statements that do not produce a result set, i.e. statements without a `SELECT`. If you're producing a result set then you need to retrieve that data. To do that you need to call `ExecuteReader` for one or more rows or `ExecuteScalar` for a single value. You can also use a data adapter and call `Fill` to populate a `DataTable` that you can then edit and save back to the database. Follow my link and use the appropriate example from there.

Comment: In this case, there's no point doing a `SELECT *` because it appears that you're not interested in the data but only whether the data exists. In that case, use `SELECT COUNT(*)` to count the matching records. Anything other than zero means there's a match in the database. As you're only interested in a single value, call `ExecuteScalar`. Also, you may not have been taught it but you should learn to parameterise your commands. See [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) for more info.

Comment: You might also like to check out [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?499888) thread. It details how to set up the login dialogue and it also provides a link to another thread that demonstrates how to do what I described above, i.e. count the records and use `ExecuteScalar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btLogin.Click
        Opencon()
        Try
         Dim dr as New DataReader 
            cmd.Connection = dhel
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from credentials_tb where Username='" & tbUser.Text & "' and Password='" & tbPwd.Text & "'"

                dr=cmd.ExecuteReader()
             If dr.Read() Then  
                MsgBox("Login Succesful.")
                dhel.Close()
                Me.Hide()
             Else
                MsgBox("Login Failed.")
             End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.  Please consider adding some notes as to what your code is doing and why you are doing it, instead of simply pasting code.